# Store {price} field without the currency?

Tags: expresso-store

in exp:resso store, is it possible to display the {price} field without the currency symbol in certain situations? e.g. {raw_price}

I want to calculate alternative currencies with a currency converter. obviously currency converters only accepts integers without currency symbols...

cheers
stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `_val` to most price related fields to get the unformatted price so

`{price_val}`

would return "20" if your item price was "$20.00"

Comment: that was it! works perfectly... where exactely is this in the docs... I knew I saw it once, but I coudn't find it yesterday!

Comment: Just below this: https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/tags/product.html#product-tag-variables

Comment: Thanks a lot! there's a lot of useful information in this section...

Comment: What's the updated link to this documentation?

Comment: https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html